# Inno Setup override default settings for /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES

Tags: installation, inno-setup, silent-installer

I want to create a silent installer without message boxes.
Inno Setup gives you the opportunity to suppress these.
Sadly there are default values and I don't know how to override them.

Here is the documentation from Inno Setup:
https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupcmdline

Example: I want to set "yes" if messagebox contains *'File exists, confirm overwrite.'* situation.
Default value would be *"no"*.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is imo moot.

By default, Inno Setup does not ask for overwrite confirmation. It asks only if you explicitly tell it so using [`confirmoverwrite` flag](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=confirmoverwrite). If you do not want the confirmation, do not use the flag.